# Xcode Swift 4 calling self.tableView.reload() to reduce number of cell rows

Tags: uitableview, tableview, swift4

After calling tableView.reload from a "delete editingStyle forRowAt", is there a way to reduce the number of table rows since the datasource array count has accordingly reduced? I would think that once a cell UI has been drawn on the tableView, it can't be removed by means of a tableView.reload. Rather, the user would have to delete the row. Let me know, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After deleting the record from the datasource array you can directly call:

```
 self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPathForDeltedItem], with: .automatic)
```

If you are using NSFetchedResultController then the flow will be:

1. Delete a record from your core data entity.
2. This will make give call to fetchResultController Delegate with action .delete
3. Remove the cell from the tableView.

Comment: Thanks Peeyush for the info and the process flow. The NSFetchedResultController is the functionality I was looking for in tying tableView and Core Data together.

Comment: You're Welcome :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I could look into NSFetchResultsController to respond to data changes and synchronize the tableView with Core Data.